# В студии wpf (C#) не видны имена объектов

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

В последнее время часто стало необходимо создавать некоторые формы в WPF и сталкиваюсь постоянно с одной и той же проблемой. После задания имен объектам (кнопки к примеру) их имена не видны в C# классе до перезагрузки студии однако все компилируется есди испольхзовать эти имена к классе но студия подчеркивает их красным. Быть может кто то сталкивался уже или же это только у меня подобные неудовства возникли?

Использую студию 2017.

Comment: думаю проще всего будет снести студию, потом стеснить кеш и все временные файлы и настройки студии, а потом поставить с нуля. Ну или сменить форточку, а за ней все это автоматически выплывет.

Comment: Пока что некогда революцию устраивать) быть может попозже сделаю а еще есть идеи ? может настройки где нибудь подкрутить ?

Comment: Для именования вы используете `x:Name="имя"`, так?

Comment: @Bulson нет просто свойство Name изменяю `Name="MyName"`